# How to compare Comma Seperated value to get existing value

Tags: mysql

I have Table as Production with field name as production_code

Production_code have value like this,

```
    Id  production_code
     1  P101,P102,P103,P105
     2  P103,P106,P102
     3  P104
     4  P102,P105,P111
```

------ I have value on PHP page like `$p_code='P102,P109'`;

Now I want to fetch rows from Table Production_code where any code is exist in production_code of variable `$p_code`

please help me .. what mysql query should i use

Comment: Is the given input should match for the total column or it should search weather that values is present in any row

Comment: Please read [ask] & show what parts you are able to do. [mcve] Also please explain how googling--eg googling your title--didn't help.

Comment: any of the value of $p_code exist in table column then it should be fetched

Comment: It's really simple: don't have a comma separated value. Instead see normalisation.

Comment: its only comma seperated value ... pls help

Comment: @user112225 Why do you have the values in a comma separated list instead of a new `N to M` table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `FIND_IN_SET`, like:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('P102', production_code) OR FIND_IN_SET('P109', production_code)
```

Comment: tnks for reply.. but $p_code have not fixed value. its coming form session and it may consist more than two comma values..

Comment: In this case, you have to split them into array and add `OR FIND_IN_SET(value, production_code)` for each value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

```
<?php 
    $p_code='P102,P109'; //example
    $condition = '';
    foreach(explode(',',$p_code) as $r){//explode convert $p_code string into array. then apply foreach for compare every element of array From database saved value
        $condition .= 'FIND_IN_SET("'.$r.'", production_code) OR ';
    }
    $condition = rtrim($condition,' OR '); //this remove last occurence of OR from condition
    echo $sql = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable
            WHERE '.$condition;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear "Gyandeep Sharma"..... its working fantastic. lots of ******* to you

Comment: what do you means by *******...?

Comment: ******* means stars